# spinner selected item sent to mysql database in Android

Tags: android, mysql

I am using two spinners in my application  one is for 'username' and second spinner for 'course'.

Still now i did load data from MySQL database and assign to spinner, its works fine! When i click on submit button in my application i want to sent those details to MySQL db.

**Declaring an Spinner**

```
       private Spinner spinner2, spinner1;

        //An ArrayList for Spinner Items

        private ArrayList<String> students1;
        private ArrayList<String> students2;

        //JSON Array

        private JSONArray result1, result2, result;

        //TextViews to display details
        private TextView textViewName1;
        private TextView textViewName2;
        private TextView textViewCourse;
        private TextView textViewSession;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity_d1);

            //Initializing the ArrayList
            students1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            students2 = new ArrayList<String>();

            //Initializing Spinner


            //Adding an Item Selected Listener to our Spinner
            //As we have implemented the class Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener to this class iteself we are passing this to setOnItemSelectedListener


            spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

            spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            //    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

            //Initializing TextViews
            textViewName1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName1);
            textViewName2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName2);
            //      textViewCourse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCourse);
            //      textViewSession = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSession);

            //This method will fetch the data from the URL

            getData1();
            getData2();
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        /*    switch (view.getId()){

                case R.id.spinner1:
                    getData1();
                    break;


                case R.id.spinner2:
                    getData2();
                    break;
            }*/
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {


            if (spinner1.getId() == R.id.spinner1) {
                //do this
                textViewName1.setText("");
            } else if (spinner2.getId() == R.id.spinner2) {
                //do this
                textViewName2.setText("");
            }

        }

        private void getData1() {
            //Creating a string request
            StringRequest stringRequest1 = new StringRequest(Config.DATA_URL1,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response1) {
                            JSONObject j1 = null;
                            try {
                                //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                                j1 = new JSONObject(response1);

                                //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                                result1 = j1.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY1);

                                //Calling method getStudents to get the students from the JSON Array
                                getStudents1(result1);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error1) {

                        }
                    });

            //Creating a request queue
            RequestQueue requestQueue1 = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

            //Adding request to the queue
            requestQueue1.add(stringRequest1);
        }

        private void getStudents1(JSONArray j1) {
            //Traversing through all the items in the json array
            for (int i = 0; i < j1.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    //Getting json object
                    JSONObject json1 = j1.getJSONObject(i);

                    //Adding the name of the student to array list
                    students1.add(json1.getString(Config.TAG_COURSE));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            //Setting adapter to show the items in the spinner
            spinner1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity_d2.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, students1));
        }

    //Initializing TextViews

    //      textViewCourse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCourse);
    //      textViewSession = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSession);

    //This method will fetch the data from the URL

     private void getData2() {
            //Creating a string request
            StringRequest stringRequest2 = new StringRequest(Config.DATA_URL2,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response2) {
                            JSONObject j2 = null;
                            try {
                                //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                                j2 = new JSONObject(response2);

                                //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                                result = j2.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);

                                //Calling method getStudents to get the students from the JSON Array
                                getStudents2(result);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error1) {

                        }
                    });

            //Creating a request queue
            RequestQueue requestQueue2 = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

            //Adding request to the queue
            requestQueue2.add(stringRequest2);
        }

        private void getStudents2(JSONArray j2) {
            //Traversing through all the items in the json array
            for (int i = 0; i < j2.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    //Getting json object
                    JSONObject json2 = j2.getJSONObject(i);

                    //Adding the name of the student to array list
                    students2.add(json2.getString(Config.TAG_USERNAME));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            //Setting adapter to show the items in the spinner
            spinner2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity_d2.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, students2));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post those values and insert into db from server side.

Comment: how can i do this?